# Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app_utils'.

> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
> Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namesp
> ace.

```
 If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to ht
```

tps://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Failed to query the value of property 'buildFlowServiceProperty'.

> Could not isolate value org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.statistics.BuildFlowService$Parameters_Decorated@54062ddb of type BuildFlowService.Parameters
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app_utils'.
> > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
> > Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the
> namespace.

```
       If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer
```

to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

j'ai essaye de changé les version de com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.0'
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20 mais sa marche pas